# How to make hover effect to show elements in a div using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm new to javascript and  i have been trying to write a  programme that changes the opacity of a div and shows it's hidden 'p' element . But when i hover the div the hidden 'p' elements in the other div appear.How do i make the 'p' element show only in the hovered div ?. Please any suggestion/advice will be appreciated. Thanks

HTML

```
<div class = "description">
    <a><img src="image.jpg" height = 330px width = 220px></a>
    <p class = "word"> image description</p>
</div>
<div class = "description">
    <a><img src="image.jpg" height = 330px width = 220px></a>
    <p class = "word"> image description</p>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.word').hide();
 $('.description').hover(function(){

     $(this).fadeTo('fast',0.6);
     $('.word').show();
 });

 $('.description').mouseleave(function(){

     $('.description').fadeTo('fast',1);
     $('.word').hide();
 }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to find the `.word` elements that are in that particular div,so you would use `$(this).find()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.word').hide();
 $('.description').hover(function(){

     $(this).fadeTo('fast',0.6);
     $(this).find('.word').show();
 });

 $('.description').mouseleave(function(){

     $(this).fadeTo('fast',1);
     $(this).find('.word').hide();
 }); 
});
```

or more succinctly

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.word').hide();
 $('.description').hover(function(){
     $(this).fadeTo('fast',0.6).find('.word').show();
 }).mouseleave(function(){
     $(this).fadeTo('fast',1).find('.word').hide();
 }); 
});
```

Also your img tags are wrong.  You mean `<img src="image.jpg" style="height: 330px; width: 220px">`

Answer (score 0):

You must use: `$( '.description > .word ')` to get child.

Comment: @Popnoodles But if he have one ".description", this code will work.

Comment: He has more than one - it says that in the question.

Comment: @Popnoodles He said "div the hidden 'p' elements in the other div appear" , he don't said have any `.description` !

Comment: `$('.word').show();` isn't `$('p').show();` It's clear what he means

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the child `p.word` element of `$(this)` in both cases:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.word').hide();
    $('.description').hover(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.6);
        $(this).find('p.words').show();
    });

    $('.description').mouseleave(function () {

        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
        $(this).find('p.words').hide();
    });
});
```

Keep in mind that if the css of `.words` is `visibility : hidden` and not `display : none` you'll need to to change `.show()` and `.hide()` to:

```
// show
$(this).find('p.words').css('visibility', 'visible');
// hide
$(this).find('p.words').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

**Working example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.word').hide();
    $('.description').hover(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.6);
        $(this).find('p.words').show();
    });

    $('.description').mouseleave(function () {

        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
        $(this).find('p.words').hide();
    });
});
```

```css
.words{
    display: none;
}
.description{
    padding: 20px;
    border: solid 2px steelblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="description">
    <p class="words">image description</p>
</div>
<div class="description">
    <p class="words">image description</p>
</div>
<div class="description">
    <p class="words">image description</p>
</div>
<div class="description">
    <p class="words">image description</p>
</div>
<div class="description">
    <p class="words">image description</p>
</div>
```